# Traversing Arrays by forEach

Tags: javascript, arrays

Trying to traverse an array into an object with key/pair (yes I know of reduce):

This is the array:

```
filtered2 = [["deviceName", "TestDevice00003"], ["hwModelName", "TestHwModel03"], ["deviceTypeName", "TestDeviceType03"], ["serviceTag", "A1A03"]]
```

But for some reason when I do forEach:

```
filtered2.forEach( (indiv) => {
  console.log([indiv[0]]+" | " +[indiv[1]])
    obj3 = {
      ...obj3,
      [[indiv[0]][0]]  : [indiv[1]]
    }
})
```

Console.log will see each (indiv) as "hwModelName | TestHwModel03"
at `[indiv[0]]+" | " +[indiv[1]]`, so both are basic strings

But the forEach function sees `[indiv[1]]` as Array ["TestHwModel03"]
So I have to go one more depth level `[indiv[1]][0]`  into the array to get the unwrapped string "TestHwModel03"

Why there this difference?

Comment: `[indiv[0]]+" | " +[indiv[1]]` is `array` + `string` + `array`. Use `indiv[0] + " | " + indiv[1]`

Comment: `[indiv[0]]` creates a new array. Is that really what you want to do? I'd expect you want to only access  `indiv[0]`

Comment: As for why `[indiv[0]]+" | " +[indiv[1]]` gives you the expected result - you'd need to read up on [type coercion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Type_coercion)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the square brackets surrounding the value.

```js
filtered2 = [["deviceName", "TestDevice00003"], ["hwModelName", "TestHwModel03"], ["deviceTypeName", "TestDeviceType03"], ["serviceTag", "A1A03"]]

let obj3 = {}

filtered2.forEach( (indiv) => {
    obj3 = {
      ...obj3,
      [indiv[0]]  : indiv[1]
    }
})

console.log(obj3)
```

Although it's much simpler to use [`Object.fromEntries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries):

```js
filtered2 = [["deviceName", "TestDevice00003"], ["hwModelName", "TestHwModel03"], ["deviceTypeName", "TestDeviceType03"], ["serviceTag", "A1A03"]]

let obj3 = Object.fromEntries(filtered2)
console.log(obj3)
```

Comment: `[indiv[0]]: indiv[1]` will work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can use reduce method on an array to convert the array to a map. Or You can use [Object.fromEntries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) if your env supports the latest version of ES2017.

```js
filtered2 = [
  ["deviceName", "TestDevice00003"],
  ["hwModelName", "TestHwModel03"],
  ["deviceTypeName", "TestDeviceType03"],
  ["serviceTag", "A1A03"],
];
const toMap = (arr = []) =>
  arr.reduce((acc, [key, value]) => {
    acc[key] = value;
    return acc;
  }, {});

console.log(toMap(filtered2))

/// Other way
console.log(Object.fromEntries(filtered2))
```